# Автоматическое заполнение полей Маршрута на встроенной на сайт карте Яндекса

Tags: yandex-maps-api

На сайте поставлена карта Яндекса, там же установлена метка организации. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на "Маршруты" происходило автоматическое заполнение полей "Откуда" (определялась геопозиция пользователя) и "Куда" (добавлялся адрес организации).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно предзадать состояние первого поля и вызвать метод определения местоположения для второго. При нажатии на кнопку "Маршруты" будет автоматически строится маршрут:

```js
ymaps.ready(function () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.753994, 37.622093],
        zoom: 9,
        // Добавим панель маршрутизации.
        controls: ['routeButtonControl']
    });

    var control = myMap.controls.get('routeButtonControl');

    // Зададим состояние панели для построения машрутов.
    control.routePanel.state.set({
        // Тип маршрутизации.
        type: 'auto',
        // Адрес или координаты пункта назначения.
        to: 'Москва',
        
    });
    
    //В точку отправления передаем местоположение пользователя
    control.routePanel.geolocate('from');

    // Зададим опции панели для построения машрутов.
    control.routePanel.options.set({
        // Запрещаем показ кнопки, позволяющей менять местами начальную и конечную точки маршрута.
        allowSwitch: false,
        // Включим определение адреса по координатам клика.
        // Адрес будет автоматически подставляться в поле ввода на панели, а также в подпись метки маршрута.
        reverseGeocoding: true
    });
});
```

```css
        html, body, #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://yandex.st/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!